# Error with \documentclass[10pt]{article}

Tags: article

I have problems with this code and I have no idea how to fix it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{NAME}
\title{TITLE}
\usepackage[paperwidth=612pt,paperheight=792pt,top=28pt,right=34pt,bottom=35pt,left=34pt]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{ABSTRACT}

\noindent \textbf{}

{\raggedright

\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{514pt}|}
\hline
\parbox{514pt} {\raggedright  \vspace{3pt}
TEXT \textbf{. } TEXT } \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}

}

\end{document}
```

The error that I got is this:

```
Command Line:   latex.exe --src --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "file.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\*****

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(file.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 1 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 ï
     »¿%\documentclass[10pt]{article}
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on file.log.
```

---

LaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

Errors: 1   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0

---

---

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your code runs for me without any problem, however there seems to be strange characters before `\documentclass` according to your posted error log. Could you check your file encoding?

Comment: I don't encounter a "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}." message either.

Comment: Unrelated to your eventual issue: `\usepackage{hyperref}` should be at the end of package loading, not somewhere in between

Answer (score 2):

you have a UTF-8 BOM sequence at the start of the file

bytes:

```
 EF BB BF
```

or if (mis) interpreted as latin1, the three characters

```
 ï  » ¿
```

best would be to use an editor that allows you to save without the byte order mark.

Comment: You could have looked for the duplicate. It took less time than writing an answer.